# Connection strings is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am developing windows application in C# and i used sql server 2008 database.I have declared my connection string in `app.config` like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="constr" connectionString="server=lexecute-pc;database=lexecute_window;integrated security=true"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

And in my .cs page i am calling connection string like this:

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
```

But when I run this page I got following exception:

> Configuration system failed to initialize

Please help me.

Comment: Your configuration file seems to be not valid xml or some config section is not defined in proper manner.. check the error message `Configuration system failed to initialize` you will get lot of answer to solve which might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this, it is working fine for me:

```
 <add name="sConnectionString"
  connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=userid;Initial Catalog=databasename;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

I hope it will help you.. :)

also you can use the website for connection strings:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Also make sure app.config starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
  <section name="yourProjectName.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

let me know if this help you. :)